# HTML create odd shaped table

Tags: html

What is a good way to create a table that looks like this:

```
                           | Horizontal header data1  |Horizontal header data2|
                           | Horizontal header data2  |Horizontal header data2|
|Vert header 1|Vert header2| data                     | data                  |
|Vert header 3|Vert header4| data                     | data                  |
|Vert header 5|Vert header6| data                     | data                  |
```

I have some solution that has a lot of serverside pre processing. 2 data structures(horizontal headers, rest of the table) and then in the HTML I just build the table in 2 parts. But is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
td{
border: 1px solid #ccc
}
table{
border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <!-- if you want to combaine 1st 2 columns  use <td colspan="2"></td> and delete 2nd <td></td> tag below --> 
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td>Horizontal header data1</td>  
  <td>Horizontal header data2</td>  
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Vert header 1</td>
  <td>Vert header 1</td> 
  <td>data</td>
  <td>data</td>
</tr>
  
<tr> 
  <td>Horizontal header data1</td>  
  <td>Horizontal header data2</td> 
  <td>data</td>
  <td>data</td> 
</tr>
  
<tr> 
  <td>Horizontal header data1</td>  
  <td>Horizontal header data2</td>
  <td>data</td>
  <td>data</td>  
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can this be made fully dynamic? like row and column count can vary? Because the only knowledge about the data i have is that it has X amount of horizontal headers and Y amount of vertical headers.

Comment: Just put empty space between `<td>` tags if u want to make column empty . it will work .

Comment: if u dont want the border between 1st and 2nd column(combain 2 columns) . replace 1st `<td></td>` with `<td colspan="2">` and remove 2nd `<td></td>`